# Minecraft DLC sharing between users on Nintendo Switch

Tags: nintendo-switch, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is Minecraft (bedrock edition) DLC available to all users on a single Nintendo Switch?

I know games are available to all users and Breath of the Wild DLC was also but I'd like to confirm Minecraft DLC is.  We have three accounts, one for me and two for my young sons, and all the purchases are done on mine.  Now they'd like to purchase in game stuff (modes, skins etc) but I'm not sure with requiring a Microsoft/Minecraft account if they'll be able to share what is bought.

If I sign up in my switch user and make the purchases, will they be available to the other users even without the my user being signed in?

Answer (score 1):

We ended up buying content on my account (with no Microsoft/Minecraft account) and no the content was not available to other users.
I then set up a Microsoft account, signed into that with my user and synced the purchases and then used the same Microsoft account for my son's user and that one now has the purchases.  That's enough for us, it allows my two sons to play with the content together with the synced user driving things.
Would it have issue with two accounts with the same Microsoft account trying to play together?  Don't know, sorry we didn't test it.

Comment: Did you have to create an additional kid account for your son in the XBox family settings? Or do you just have one xbox account, without any family setups. For me the inventory on the kids account does not show all my xbox-accounts purchasements. Actually none of them. But it seems to be able to connect to my xBox accoun.

Comment: No I just used one Microsoft account and ended up signing one of my sons in.  I wasn't aware of the family sharing which sounds like a better solution 